# Using switch statements for a playing cards program (Java)

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have my program figured out so far, it's just that I'm not understanding these instructions I was given (or at least understanding how to do them).

When I type 10, it prints out "10 of", but when I try to type `10S` for 10 of Spades, it only prints out "Spades."

Hopefully, someone here can give me either a solution or point me in the right direction on how to solve my problem:

> Use a SWITCH statement to assign the result variable an initial value - the value of the card
>
> Use a second SWITCH statement to concatenate to the result variable the card's suit"

here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class CardConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //will hold string that user will input
        String card, face, suit, result;
        
        //getting input from user and telling them correct format
        System.out.println("Please enter either the number or face value intial of a card followed by the initial of it's suit (ie. QH for Queen of Hearts)");
        card = keyboard.nextLine();
        //gets first value
        face = card.substring(0);
        //sets substring for 10 only
        //substring for after all single digit/letter card faces
        suit = card.substring(1);
        
        
        //to print face and word of
        switch (face)
        {
        case "10":
            System.out.println("10 of ");
            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("2 of ");
            break;  
        case "3":
            System.out.println("3 of ");
            break;
        case "4":
            System.out.println("4 of ");
            break;  
        case "5":
            System.out.println("5 of ");
            break;
        case "6":
            System.out.println("6 of ");
            break;
        case "7":
            System.out.println("7 of ");
            break;
        case "8":
            System.out.println("8 of ");
            break;
        case "9":
            System.out.println("9 of ");
            break;
        case "J":
            System.out.println("Jack of ");
            break;
        case "Q":
            System.out.println("Queen of ");
            break;
        case "K":
            System.out.println("King of ");
            break;
        case "A":
            System.out.println("Ace of ");
            break;  
        }   
        //to print out card suit
        switch (suit)
            {
            case "H":
                    System.out.println("Hearts");
                break;
            case "C":
                System.out.println("Clubs");
                break;  
            case "S":
                System.out.println("Spades");
                break;
            case "D":
                System.out.println("Diamonds");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `card.substring(0);` gives you what value? Is that anything in the case statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem starts at `card.substring(0);`, which equals `card` because the substring from the start of the String. Maybe you wanted `card.charAt(0);`? But that is also wrong because `"10S"` will have three characters, two for the face value.

You'll need to handle a three-character input specially or be smarter about the `substring`-ing.

You know the suit will always be the last character, so use the length of the string to `charAt` for that.

```
int suitIndex = s.length() - 1;
String suit = ""+s.charAt(suitIndex);
String face = s.substring(0,suitIndex);
```

You can also simplify the cases

```
case "J":
    System.out.println("Jack of ");
    break;
case "Q":
    System.out.println("Queen of ");
    break;
case "K":
    System.out.println("King of ");
    break;
case "A":
    System.out.println("Ace of ");
    break;  
default:
    System.out.println(face + " of "); // handle all the numbers
    break;
```

Comment: Your suggestion was actually the perfect solution, thanks a lot